# How can I turn off sessions in symfony 2/3?

Tags: php, rest, symfony

I don't need to use sessions in my rest(stateless) api and if I turn off them, it's causing an error.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I did it about a year ago with symfony 2.7, on this I do not remember what kind of error message. An error caused when user doesn't send PHP_SESSION cookie.

Comment: you say "it is causing an error", we need to know what is the error to be able to help you... and if you don't have error on your current code, i don't understant your problem...

Answer (score 9):

You may try using `stateless` in
**security.yml**

```
security:
    firewalls:
        main:
            stateless:  true
```

[Read Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#stateless-authentication)

Hope it's what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks. now i'm starting create new api and need to know in advance

Answer (score -1):

Make the firewall security to false:

```
security:
  providers:
    in_memory:
      memory: ~
  firewalls:
    main:
      stateless: true
      security: false
```